# ServiceNow - Filtering a List Collector with a script

Tags: servicenow

On my form I have a variable that is auto populated on load.  The value is from the user profile.  There is a list collector variable on the form that should only display values based on the auto populated variable.  I have written a catalog onChange script to filter the list collector.

```
`function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading) {
 var collectorName = 'cn';  
 var filterString = '';
 var dynamicQuery = "" ;
 var order=g_form.getValue('autopopulatedvariable');
 dynamicQuery = "u_order="+order;
 try{
    var myListCollector = g_list.get(collectorName);
    myListCollector.reset();
    myListCollector.setQuery(dynamicQuery);
 }
 catch(e){
   //Reset the filter query 
   window[collectorName + 'g_filter'].reset();
   window[collectorName + 'g_filter'].setQuery(dynamicQuery);
   window[collectorName + 'acRequest'](null);
 }
```

}`

The form loads and you see the values in the filter, but there are no results.  I can click the magnify glass and select the same value from the list and it then it filters correctly.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Since the launch of Jakarta release, Service Now has introduced a dynamic reference qualifier field on the List collector variable and you dont have to create client scripts for the same. 
[image: List Collector]

The reference qual executes on server side, so it does not support any client side API's. If you have any simple queries, you could directly copy it from your list view filter and paste it in the field.

If your query is dynamic and depends on other variables on the form. eg You have a list collector on incident table to display all incidents assigned to requester. You can add this in your reference qual

```js
javascript:'assigned_to='+current.variables.requested_for;
```

Here requested_for is the variable that stores requester name

For your case, you could add the query as

```js
javascript:'u_order='+current.variables.autopopulatedvariable;
```

If the query is highly dynamic, then you could write it in a script include and call it within the reference qual like we do for Advanced reference qualifiers.

Here is a nice blog on the same topic: [link](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_blog&sys_id=524d6229dbd0dbc01dcaf3231f961903)